# On click of input box in table return cell value on the same row as input box but different column

Tags: javascript, input, onclick, html-table

I've been trying to do this: When the user clicks one of the input boxes in the table to enter their username the Javascript will return the cell's value that is in the next column (job id) to a variable, so then I can use that variable which is the primary key in the mysql table to update the database with the username they enter.

I have found some code that outputs the index of the input box to an alert.

I need help editing this Javascript so it finds the value of the column (job id) next to the input box the user clicks into.

```
    <script>var list = document.getElementById("job_table"),
    items = list.getElementsByTagName("input");

 list.onclick = function(e) {
    var evt = e || window.event,
    src = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
    var myIndex = findIndex(src);    
        alert(myIndex);
};

function findIndex( elem ) {
     var i, len = items.length;
     for(i=0; i<len; i++) {
         if (items[i]===elem) {
            return i;
         }
     }


       return -1;
 }</script>
```

below is the table HTML

```
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <table id="job_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Enter Username Then Press Log On Button</th>
      <th>Job Id</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <form action="" method="post">
          <input  type="text" ">
          <button type="submit">Log off</button>                                    
          <button type="submit">Log on</button>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <form action="" method="post">
          <input type="text">
          <button type="submit">Log off</button>                        
          <button type="submit">Log on</button>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>68</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Razor303/642o3uf7/7/)

After all day searching I've found what I'm looking for,  [JSFIDDLE JQUERY ANSWER](http://jsfiddle.net/Razor303/cjza90zo/8/)

Comment: What is the current problem? When you try to run it, what happens?

Comment: the first code I posted the onclick handler script finds the index of the input box you click into, I need the value of the column next to it (job id) passed to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I extended your list.onclick handler script to get the job id of the current row by clicking into the input field:

```
list.onclick = function(e) {
    var evt = e || window.event,
    src = evt.target || evt.srcElement;

    if (src.tagName != 'INPUT')
        return; 

    //var myIndex = findIndex(src);    

    // fetching TR parent row of clicked input.
    var parentRow = src.parentNode;
    do {
        parentRow = parentRow.parentNode;
    }
    while(parentRow.tagName != 'TR');

    var jobIdTd = parentRow.getElementsByTagName('TD')[1] // 1 is index of job id in this row;

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = jobIdTd.innerHTML;
}
```

Your click handler is used on the whole table, so it's necessary to know which table row contains your input field. With the `do/while loop`, you go up in the element hierarchy to fetch the row. After that, you fetch all including `td` elements of this row. The index of your input element isn't really necessary for that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I've decided to use jquery, I found the code after searching all day....

Comment: np, there can be not enough jQuery :P. Tick the answer as solution.